# Manageable Router with multiple wifi networks capability

Tags: wifi, networking, router

I would like to know if such device exists and what are your models recommendations if so.

The problem I'm trying to solve is to create multiple Wi-Fi networks each of then with limited band speed. That is because in my development group we need to test apps with different speed scenarios both for download and upload capabilities.

With such device I would create something like:

```
WiFi Network 1 - 1 Mbps download speed
                128 Kbps upload speed
WiFi Network 2 - 56 Kbps download speed
                 28 Kbps upload speed
WiFi Network 3 - 1 Gbps download speed
                 128 Mbps upload speed
...
```

If such device does not exist (yet) what would be your recommendations for a Manageable Router with different Access Points plugged to it?

Like:

```
    Manageable Router 1 (4 network ports):
         Port 1: wifi access point 1 (config 1 above)
         Port 2: wifi access point 2 (config 2 above)
         Port 3: wifi access point 3 (config 3 above)
         ...
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: The Asus RT-AC3200 has this feature if i recall correctly.

Comment: @gabygg4 Hi there, thank you for your suggestion, I was through the specifications and it seems that it is exactly what we need. You can Add it as an answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I could not find the ability specific to the wifi network for the RT-AC3200 that @gabygg4 recommended.  I was able to determine that you can do this using [adaptive qos](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1013333) on this router.

In fact on most of the RT series routers you can do this with.

Going this route will be a little more cumbersome if you have a client that needs to test on two separate bandwidths back to back.  To simplify that process you could simply set up some .reg files to change the mac address on the computer with a double click.